# Jython: parsing text to float containing commas

Tags: floating-point, jython, string-parsing

How can I parse a float scanned from a sheet as text, containing commas?

```
txt = "1,903.44"
value = float(txt) # This fails due to ',' in string
```

UPDATE: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm using jython 2.5, which doesn't have the locale module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt = "1,903.44"
value = float(txt.replace(',', ''))
```

If you need localization, this won't really work but it does the trick if you know that commas are your separators.

Comment: This works the easiest, considering I don't have the locale module. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`locale.atof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) after `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`.

Comment: +1 Just wanted to add that if the OP is dealing with monetary values, it may be wiser to use the decimal package instead of floating points.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723356/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-floating-precision-data-types

Comment: You're right, this is for parsing an invoice to get a monetary amount.

Comment: You can use locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'] to get the separator character for a locale-safe version of the replace idea. Except in Jython, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

You could strip the commas:

```
txt = txt.replace(',', '')
value = float(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the decimal package when dealing with monetary values to avoid [well-documented pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723356/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-floating-precision-data-types) that occur when using floating points.

```
from decimal import Decimal
txt = txt.replace (',', '')
value = Decimal(txt)
```

As noted by other posters, this only works if your locale is known to use ',' as thousands separator, but should get you going in the right direction.